# How do I effectively move a const wchar* into an std::wstring?

Tags: c++

Recently I've been working on a project and I encountered a problem where I'd be constantly copying a `const wchar*` into a `wstring`. Is there any way to kind of "move" the pointer into the string so it doesn't copy it?

I was hoping for a direct way to do it but I failed to find any rescources about this

Comment: Presumably you mean a `std::wstring`, but what would the purpose of "moving" a pointer "into" a string be? How would that even work? Do you want a string-like wrapper around a C string pointer? If so, consider a *string view*, as in [`std::wstring_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: What I am basically aiming at is `moving` the contents of a a pointer into the string(aka changing the string pointer internally) but it doesn't seem like there is a direct way to do so

Comment: You can't because that would be impractical and dangerous. `std::string` and related types manage their own memory and cannot take ownership of an arbitrary pointer. The *view* doesn't take ownership, so it might be what you want. As noted in the documentation the pointer being viewed must outlive the view, and if that's not the case, perhaps copying into a `std::wstring` is a good alternative as that is self-contained. Copying strings is generally not expensive computationally if done only when necessary.

Comment: If you can get that working, worth posting a self-answer with your solution as that can help others.

Comment: Why do you deal with `wchar_t*` instead of only `std::wstring` in your project?

Comment: You can move a pointer into another pointer - sure. But you cannot move what a pointer points to (in your case a character string) into an object - that requires copying.

Comment: Does the pointer point to a core constant string literal, or is it returned from a C string function? There's no way to put a pointer inside `std::basic_string`, but - depending on how the pointer is created - there's a workaround to minimize its overhead.

Comment: It points to a core constant string literal @Red.Wave

Comment: If longer than 7 characters, I would make it a `constexpr std::wstring_view` in the visible scope and avoid copying into `std::string` as far as I can. I would use the std `sv` UDL and capture with `auto`:  `constexpr auto str=L"12345678"sv;`   Otherwise, I would use the `s` UDL to make a small string and store as `wstring`: `L"1234567"s;`. UTF16 is my preference over wide string so `u16` prefix is better than `w` and `u` prefix is better than `L` for literals: `constexpr auto str=u"1234567"s;` or `constexpr auto str=u"12345678"sv;` the 7 character limit is based on my speculation on x64 SBO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to replace a `std::wstring`'s internal data pointer with your own pointer.  And even if you could somehow do so through some hacking, there is simply no way to tell `std::wstring` to ignore managing that pointer.

So, you will just have to copy the `wchar*` data into the `std::wstring` and let it handle its own memory.

Otherwise, don't use `wchar*` to begin with, just use `std::wstring` by itself.

Or, depending on your use-case, you might consider using [`std::wstring_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) or [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) to wrap your `wchar*` data without having to make a full `std::wstring` out of it.